# SELECT and double CONCAT from mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql

I've just solved the issue, but it's certainly not the best solution.

Here is DB table with custom fileds to each item, like this:

```
id_item     Name    Value
1           name1   val1
1           name2   val2
1           name3   val3
2           name4   val4
3           name5   val5
3           name6   val6
```

I can't select all of this without CONCAT, because table is too big and i have restriction to select no more than 500 rows at a time

Therefore, i made this query:

```
SELECT
    id_item, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':::::', name, value) SEPARATOR ';;;;;') custom
FROM
    custom_field_value
WHERE
    GROUP BY id
ORDER BY
    id
```

So a have an array to each item in php:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_item] => 12345
            [custom] => name1:::::value1;;;;;name2:::::value2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_item] => 12346
            [custom] => name3:::::value4;;;;;name5:::::value6
        )

)
```

Then i have to explode it twice to get final result. Is there a better way to solve the issue?

May be exists some solution to get from DB an array with final rows in it? Like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_item] => 12345
            [name1] => value1
            [name2] => value2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_item] => 12346
            [name3] => value3
            [name4] => value4
            [name5] => value5
        )

)
```

Does it?

Comment: Why don't you just do an ordinary query with `LIMIT 500`?

Comment: I did it, using LIMIT and OFFSET in the loop, then merged small queries to one array. So there is a difference to select 10 000 concat rows and 60 000 without concatenation

Comment: If you're going to call it in a loop, why do you need to limit the number of rows selected?

Comment: The difference is that SQL will waste lots of time concatenating, when you're just going to split them back up in PHP. Why do you tnink you need to do this?

Comment: Because of big workload, we have restriction to select from DB by small parts (500 rows at once)

Comment: If you do it with `GROUP_CONCAT`, you'll do fewer queries, but the workload of each will be greater. Also, when you use non-zero `OFFSET`, it still has to re-calculate all the rows before that block, so it can find the offset in the results. So all these queries will be very expensive due to all the concatenating. Just do simple queries with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

Comment: I think you are right, but concatenation takes much less time, then many queries in the loop. It's like 0.7 sec without concatenation and 0.1 with it

Comment: Even with `LIMIT 500 OFFSET 8000`?

Comment: Yes! I was surprised how fast it is with CONCAT when tried it, but it seems to me it might be a better way. ':::::' and ';;;;;' look very bad

Comment: I guess MySQL is smart enough to do the limit using the index on the ID field, before it does all the concatenation. So this is probably the best way then.